# Как вывести определенную часть из ошибки

Tags: angular, angular2, angular8, angular10

У меня есть ошибка, она выводится вся, а мне хотелось бы вывести только Invalid password

```
Store.Shared.Common.Exceptions.ServerException: Invalid password
   at Store.BusinessLogicLayer.Services.AccountService.SignInAsync(LoginModel model) in D:\Store\Store.BusinessLogicLayer\Services\AccountService.cs:line 137
   at Store.PresentationLayer.Controllers.AccountController.SignInAsync(LoginModel model)
```

Я пытаюсь конвертировать так

```
 let error: string[] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(errorMessage.error));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С типом исключения:

```js
let errorString = `Store.Shared.Common.Exceptions.ServerException: Invalid password
   at Store.BusinessLogicLayer.Services.AccountService.SignInAsync(LoginModel model) in D:\Store\Store.BusinessLogicLayer\Services\AccountService.cs:line 137
   at Store.PresentationLayer.Controllers.AccountController.SignInAsync(LoginModel model)`;

let end = errorString.indexOf("at");
let message = errorString.slice(0, end).trim();
console.log(message); // "Store.Shared.Common.Exceptions.ServerException: Invalid password"
```

Если только сообщение без типа исключения, то так:

```js
let errorString = `Store.Shared.Common.Exceptions.ServerException: Invalid password
   at Store.BusinessLogicLayer.Services.AccountService.SignInAsync(LoginModel model) in D:\Store\Store.BusinessLogicLayer\Services\AccountService.cs:line 137
   at Store.PresentationLayer.Controllers.AccountController.SignInAsync(LoginModel model)`;

let start = errorString.indexOf(":");
let end = errorString.indexOf("at");
let message = errorString.slice(start +1, end).trim();
console.log(message); // "Invalid password"
```

Comment: все работает)Спасибо)

Comment: можете пожалуйста помочь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1220231/Почему-получаю-ошибку-cannot-read-property-errormessage-of-undefined

Comment: @Dmitriy не могу помочь - не понимаю  в чем у вас проблема

Comment: Спасибо большое что откликнулись) Уже исправил проблему)